# Only allow calls to endpoint from frontend Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am new to Django Rest Framework. My API is used in 2 ways:

1. I have a React frontend
2. As a normal REST API returning JSON

However, I don't want the endpoints called for my frontend to be able to be called in the normal REST API. **Specifically, I want those endpoints to only be able to be reached when called from my frontend React app.** How can I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not mistaken you are asking for host restrictions means your endpoint can only be called from a specific host than do just add your host cors whitelist. You can configure it using django cors header package

Comment: Hi thanks!! This makes sense but can I do this for only some endpoints? Thanks!

Comment: No it's will be for all the endpoint but you can make a middleware to check requests host and filter out it there

Comment: I see, so instead of using CORS, I would check in each request what the host is?

Comment: Yes as you have to filter some specific urls